# Very Beginning of Differential Calculus - Growth and Decay

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

> Suppose a population at time $t$, $P(t)$, satisfies $10P'(t)=P(t)$. If $P(0)=2$, what is $P(20)$?

I was given this question. I am nearing the end of calculus 1 and my book sticks this in kind of as an aside. I know that $P=Ce^{kt}$ and I also know that $\frac{dP}{dt}=kP$. However, I cannot make heads or tails out of this problem - I have no idea what to do? What steps should I take in order to solve the problem?

Comment: Can you see that $k=1/10$?

Comment: Like I said - I'm a super beginner. Can you explain how $k=\frac1{10}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using separation of variables, you get $\frac{P'}{P} = \frac{1}{10}$. (Here, you divide both sides by 10 and $P$.) Integrating both sides, you get $ln P(t) = t/10 + C$. Since $P(0) = 2$, $C = ln 2$. Thus, $ln P(t) = t/10 + ln 2$, which rearranges to $P(t) = 2 e^{t/10}$. Then $P(20) = 2 e^2$.

Comment: Can you explain your first sentence further? @AmyNgo

Comment: Divide both sides of your ODE by 10P(t).

Comment: what is my ODE?

Comment: ODE = ordinary differential equation.

Comment: Is that $\frac{dP}{dt}=kP$?

Comment: Yes. Terminology is very important in learning math, so please familiarize yourself with definitions and terms before attempting to "do" math.